# Simple C# console app does not work on other PC

Tags: c#, console-application, exe

I'm so newbie about programming, just started to learn 1-2 weeks ago, I didn't learn before programing. I started the process with making a very basic console application in C# language and I used for this the Visual Studio program.

The application is having the really basic functions like: asking a number in the console, writing the answer in line, and added extra stuff, to change the console background white.

The code is working well, the debug didn't find any problem, and when I'm clicking on the exe file from the folder of the Debug, it runs as well, stops before the questions, etc. At the end of the code there is the `Console.ReadKey();` too. (I'm not using database for asking the data or anything, just the simple `Console.WriteLine()`, or `Console.ReadLine()` commands I used, really, the basic stuff).

So it's working well even if I clicked on the exe file, and even when I use Visual Studio to debug it.

The problem is, I wanted to send to my friends, just to show them, what is my very first project.

The goal was if they click on the exe, they should see the same white backgrounded console app what I coded, and could answer the simple questions in it. But however I sent the program, the console is just showing up for a second with black background, writing out something and disappearing (it is so fast I can't even read what is it writing in the window).

My friends does not have Visual Studio, but they have the newest .NET, and the antivirus is loving the code too (I mean antivirus was checking the code but accepted it to run). I was trying to zip in the whole application folder too, and whatever I find in the Visual Studio's app folder, but the result is the same, exe is just a showing-disappearing console black console.

Which folders or what files should I send to my friends whose does not have Visual Studio just to be able to use my console app? Should I export somehow in Visual Studio the project (I didn't find any option for it)? the full code: [a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wf8WuczcAdWNC2BXa1viAPH6t4Ab8WdJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please can you do two things: 1) Format your question into paragraphs so it's not just a huge wall of text. 2) Add the failing code!

Comment: I would suggest running the app from an existing command line - then you'll be able to see what the error is.

Comment: You should  find you project root folder  by right click on the solution from visual studio and then copy this folder to show your friend or run on other computers, run "exe file" from this folder , or you can create a wizard from your project from visual studio

Comment: Please put your whole code! Also, try to run your program from the cmd (command prompt). You just need to search cmd and open it then do cd path\to\program then do program.exe (or whatever the name is.)!

Comment: Thank you a lot all of your fast answers, i'm going to try all of it now. Because the code is a bit long, i can share this drive link: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wf8WuczcAdWNC2BXa1viAPH6t4Ab8WdJ/view?usp=sharing) (sorry, i didn't share code before, i hope you guys can see the code in the txt file) This is the whole code what i used in Visual Studio. I need a bit time to test all the other answers, cos i have now only my pc, but i'll come back when i got all the results! Thank you again the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is the Windows Explorer trying to protect your friends from malicious code. Whenever you download something from the web, the Explorer adds a mark in the metadata of the file that execution of this file is blocked. This even continues through zip archives, i.e. if you download a zip and use the Windows Explorer to unzip, all files in there will have this mark set as well. You can check by going into the file properties where you should see an *Unblock* button, especially for the executable.

There are two solutions here:

1. You could unblock every single executable file or dll (works if there are not too many)
2. You can rename your zip archive and change the extension to txt and tell your friends to undo this after downloading.

Comment: Thank you soo much! Finally i reached on other pc, if i zip the whole program folder with everything, and I install the .net core on that pc, from the Debug folder the exe will work! Thank you, it was so usefull!